# Bootstrap Admin Panel Radio Button Hide and Show

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

Here is the link to the admin panel i am using, bootstrap themed
https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index.html

I am trying to add a radio button that hides and shows a `div` holding some drop downs. Here is an image of that

[image]

on Open it shows the `div` below, on close it dissappears.

The closest I got to making my dream a reality is that it worked but the radio buttons (the dark circles in the radio button) wasn't working, neither options were checked and even if I wanted to click them it would run the function but not color.

Here is the code I have

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked> Open
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1"> Closed
      </label>
    </div>
    <label for="openingHour" class="col-sm-2 control-label">From: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option>12:00 AM</option>
        <option>12:30 AM</option>
        <option>1:00 AM</option>
        <option>1:30 AM</option>
        <option>2:00 AM</option>
        <option>2:30 AM</option>
        <option>3:00 AM</option>
        <option>3:30 AM</option>
        <option>4:00 AM</option>
        <option>4:30 AM</option>
        <option>5:00 AM</option>
        <option>5:30 AM</option>
        <option>6:00 AM</option>
        <option>6:30 AM</option>
        <option>7:00 AM</option>
        <option>7:30 AM</option>
        <option>8:00 AM</option>
        <option>8:30 AM</option>
        <option>9:00 AM</option>
        <option>9:30 AM</option>
        <option>10:00 AM</option>
        <option>10:30 AM</option>
        <option>11:00 AM</option>
        <option>11:30 AM</option>
        <option>12:00 PM</option>
        <option>12:30 PM</option>
        <option>1:00 PM</option>
        <option>1:30 PM</option>
        <option>2:00 PM</option>
        <option>2:30 PM</option>
        <option>3:00 PM</option>
        <option>3:30 PM</option>
        <option>4:00 PM</option>
        <option>4:30 PM</option>
        <option>5:00 PM</option>
        <option>5:30 PM</option>
        <option>6:00 PM</option>
        <option>6:30 PM</option>
        <option>7:00 PM</option>
        <option>7:30 PM</option>
        <option>8:00 PM</option>
        <option>8:30 PM</option>
        <option>9:00 PM</option>
        <option>9:30 PM</option>
        <option>10:00 PM</option>
        <option>10:30 PM</option>
        <option>11:00 PM</option>
        <option>11:30 PM</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="closingHour" class="col-sm-2 control-label">To: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option>12:00 AM</option>
        <option>12:30 AM</option>
        <option>1:00 AM</option>
        <option>1:30 AM</option>
        <option>2:00 AM</option>
        <option>2:30 AM</option>
        <option>3:00 AM</option>
        <option>3:30 AM</option>
        <option>4:00 AM</option>
        <option>4:30 AM</option>
        <option>5:00 AM</option>
        <option>5:30 AM</option>
        <option>6:00 AM</option>
        <option>6:30 AM</option>
        <option>7:00 AM</option>
        <option>7:30 AM</option>
        <option>8:00 AM</option>
        <option>8:30 AM</option>
        <option>9:00 AM</option>
        <option>9:30 AM</option>
        <option>10:00 AM</option>
        <option>10:30 AM</option>
        <option>11:00 AM</option>
        <option>11:30 AM</option>
        <option>12:00 PM</option>
        <option>12:30 PM</option>
        <option>1:00 PM</option>
        <option>1:30 PM</option>
        <option>2:00 PM</option>
        <option>2:30 PM</option>
        <option>3:00 PM</option>
        <option>3:30 PM</option>
        <option>4:00 PM</option>
        <option>4:30 PM</option>
        <option>5:00 PM</option>
        <option>5:30 PM</option>
        <option>6:00 PM</option>
        <option>6:30 PM</option>
        <option>7:00 PM</option>
        <option>7:30 PM</option>
        <option>8:00 PM</option>
        <option>8:30 PM</option>
        <option>9:00 PM</option>
        <option>9:30 PM</option>
        <option>10:00 PM</option>
        <option>10:30 PM</option>
        <option>11:00 PM</option>
        <option>11:30 PM</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I deleted the js as I don't want anyone getting confused. I hope this helps and doesn't cause too much bother.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the data-toggle? It's clean and simple.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dropdowns"> Open
    </label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dropdowns" checked> Closed
    </label>
</div>
<div id="dropdowns" class="collapse">
    <!-- section containing dropdown values -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

**html**

```
<input type="radio" id="open" />open
<input type="radio" id="close" />close

    <div class="content">
      <P>
      Your stuff here
      </P>
    </div>

    <div class="content2">
      <P>
      Some other stuff
      </P>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
  display: none;
}

.content2 {
  display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#open").click(function(){
    $(".content").animate({height: "toggle"}, 500);
    $(".content2").hide();
  });
  $("#close").click(function(){
    $(".content").hide();
    $(".content2").animate({height: "toggle"}, 500);
  });
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5gw42nwo/)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this DEMO

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#open').attr('checked', true);
       $('#open').click(function() {
       if($('#open').is(':checked')) { $('#divId').removeClass('hidden');}
    });
     $('#close').click(function() {
       if($('#close').is(':checked')) { $('#divId').addClass('hidden');}
    });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <input type="radio" id="open" name="admin"/>open
    <input type="radio" id="close" name="admin"/>close


        <div class="well" id="divId">     
          Some other stuff

        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```